# how can I use jquery addClass when selecting a tr to override a nth-child class on a parent div?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using this to select a tr when clicked on to change the color of a tr.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4sn38/3/

but when I use a nth-child class on the parent div to set the tr background, my addClass isn't getting added.  How can I use the nth-child class in tandem with my jquery addClass function?

this is what I'm trying to do

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4sn38/

this didn't work

```
$(".list tr:nth-child(1)").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

this changes the color, but then I can't remove it when another is clicked

```
$(this).css('background','blue');
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there is a problem with css specificity http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sUjQW/1/

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to do

Comment: haha, well you fixed it!! Thanks, make and an answer and I'll accept, although the answer by @adeneo also was the cause of the issue. Thanks

Comment: since you have the answer already from @adeneo accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javascript seems to be working just fine, the issue is not being more specific with your CSS, as this

```
.list tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #CCC; 
}
```

is more specific than this:

```
tr.selected {
    background-color: #FFCF8B;
}
```

so you have to change it to

```
.list tr.selected {
    background-color: #FFCF8B;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sn38/5/)

[Read more on CSS specificity!](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Thank you, this is correct, @Arun P Johnny also helped in comments first.  Not to sure what SO etiquette is though for accepting answers… Definitely up voting you though.. Thanks