# CSS nth-child is over-riding jQuery click highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with row striping, set by CSS, and I also have a click function in jQuery. My code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.datarow', function() {
  $(".datarow").removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
  // other code for row select
});
```

```css
#datatable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable tr .highlight {
  background-color: #fbbc05;
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable">
<tr class="datarow">...</tr>
...
</table>
```

The jQuery row highlighting doesn't work.

But, if I remove the CSS nth-child code, then the jQuery does work as expected.

So the CSS nth-child highlighting is over-ruling the jQuery highlighting the one row when clicked on.

How can I get both working together?

I tried following this answer [how can I use jquery addClass when selecting a tr to override a nth-child class on a parent div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222387/how-can-i-use-jquery-addclass-when-selecting-a-tr-to-override-a-nth-child-class) by increasing my ".highlight" to "#datatable tr .highlight" but still no luck.

Comment: `#datatable tr .highlight`- that would select elements _inside_ the `tr` that have the class `highlight`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get both working together?

Well your CSS is incorrect to begin with:

```
#datatable tr .highlight {
  background-color: #fbbc05;
}
```

Says an element inside a `tr` has a class of `highlight` but your jquery is applying the class directly to the `tr` so you should use:

```
#datatable tr.highlight {
  background-color: #fbbc05;
}
```

The subtle difference is the single space between the `tr` and `.highlight`.

```
tr .hightlight {}
```

is VERY different from

```
tr.hightlight {}
```

I'd also HIGHLY recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  Your CSS is very tightly coupled to your html.

Comment: Damn! Good catch!